# Poisson equation and FEM

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I am trying to solve $u_{xx}+u_{yy}=-[(3x+x^2)y(1-y)+(3y+y^2)x(1-x)] e^{x+y},$ for $0<x<1,0<y<1,$ and homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions $u(x,y)=x(1-x)y(1-y)e^{x+y}$ by an analytical method, a FEM method and NDSolve and then plot all solutions to a common graph. But for the analytical method I use:

```
NDSolveValue[{\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Del]\), \({x, y}\), \(2\)]\(u[x, 
 y]\)\) == [(3 x + x^2)*y*(y - 1) + (3 y + y^2)*x*(x - 1)]*
Exp[x + y], 
DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == x*(1 - x)*y*(1 - y)*Exp[x + y], 
True]}, u, {x, 
  y} \[Element] Disk[]]
Plot3D[%[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] Disk[]]
```

which doesn't work. I tried to make a FEM method, but it didn't work. For example, I tried for NDSolve`FEM`:

```
bndmesh = 
ToBoundaryMesh[
"Coordinates" -> {{0, 0}, {0.5, 0}, {0.5, 1}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 
  1}}, "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 
    4}, {4, 1}, {2, 5}, {5, 6}, {6, 3}, {3, 2}}]}];
mesh = ToElementMesh[bndmesh];
d = If[x <= 0.5, 1, 10];
usol = NDSolve[
Laplacian[
  u[x, y], {x, y}] == (3 x + x^2)*y*(y - 1) + (3 y + y^2)*
   x*(x - 1)*Exp[x + y], 
DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == x*(1 - x)*y*(1 - y)*Exp[x + y], 
  True] \[Element] mesh][[1]];
{bndmesh["Wireframe"], mesh["Wireframe"], 
Plot3D[u[x, y] /. usol, {x, y} \[Element] mesh]}
```

Comment: You need to clarify your question. `NDSolve` never provides an analytical solution. Do you perhaps want several solutions, a numerical solution **and** an analytical solution?

Answer (score 6):

Works just fine once you fix the syntax error - you can not have stray []s in the expression:

```
NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[
     u[x, y], {x, y}] == (3 x + x^2)*y*(y - 1) + (3 y + y^2)*x*(x - 1)*
      Exp[x + y], 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == x*(1 - x)*y*(1 - y)*Exp[x + y], 
    True]}, u, Element[ {x, y}, Disk[]]];
Plot3D[%[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] Disk[]]
```

Concerning your question about the usage of FEM in this case, please see the [FEM Options tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementOptions.html), especially [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementOptions.html#62890509) and [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementOptions.html#1993509248)

[image]

For the second FEM code you also need to fix the wrong argument structure to `NDSolve`:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
bndmesh = 
  ToBoundaryMesh[
   "Coordinates" -> {{0, 0}, {0.5, 0}, {0.5, 1}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 
      1}}, "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 
        4}, {4, 1}, {2, 5}, {5, 6}, {6, 3}, {3, 2}}]}];
mesh = ToElementMesh[bndmesh];
d = If[x <= 0.5, 1, 10];
usol = NDSolve[{Laplacian[
       u[x, y], {x, y}] == (3 x + x^2)*y*(y - 1) + (3 y + y^2)*
        x*(x - 1)*Exp[x + y], 
     DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == x*(1 - x)*y*(1 - y)*Exp[x + y], 
      True]}, u, {x, y} \[Element] mesh][[1]];

{bndmesh["Wireframe"], mesh["Wireframe"], 
 Plot3D[u[x, y] /. usol, {x, y} \[Element] mesh]}
```

[image]

Things then work just fine.

Comment: what about FEM and an analytical method? Can we calculate them?

Comment: @George, what about it?

Comment: See my comment above

Answer (score 2):

> But for the analytical method I use: NDSolveValue

`NDSolveValue` is not analytical solver. It is numerical. Analytical solution is done using `DSolve`. But V 12.1 can not solve it. But this is the code (this is for the case of zero boundary conditions on all edges)

```
ClearAll[u, x, y];
pde = Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 
       -((3 x + x^2) y (1 - y) + (3 y + y^2) x (1 - x)) Exp[x + y];
bc = {u[0, y] == 0, u[1, y] == 0, u[x, 0] == 0, u[x, 1] == 0};
DSolve[{pde, bc}, u[x, y], {x, y}]
```

For whatever its worth, here is the analytical solution from Maple which can solve it. I converted it back to Mathematica syntax and plotted it. This is on the square, not on a disk, since you said for `0<x<1,0<y<1`

```
pde:=VectorCalculus:-Laplacian(u(x,y),[x,y])=
      -((3*x + x^2)*y*(1 - y) + (3*y + y^2)*x*(1 - x))*exp(x + y);
ic:=u(0, y) = 0, u(1, y) = 0, u(x, 0) = 0, u(x, 1) = 0;
sol:=pdsolve([pde,ic],u(x,y))
```

$$
u \left( x,y \right) =\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }-16\,{\frac {\sin \left( n
\pi\,y \right)  \left(  \left( -1/2\,{\pi}^{2}{n}^{2}+1/2 \right) 
 \left( -1 \right) ^{n}{{\rm e}^{1-\pi\,n \left( x-2 \right) }}+1/2\,
 \left( -1 \right) ^{n} \left( \pi\,n+1 \right)  \left( x\pi\, \left( 
x-1 \right) n-{x}^{2}-x+1 \right)  \left( \pi\,n-1 \right) {{\rm e}^{2
\,\pi\,n+x+1}}-{{\rm e}^{-\pi\,n \left( x-2 \right) }}+ \left( 
 \left( {x}^{2}-x \right) \pi\,n-{x}^{2}-x+1 \right) {{\rm e}^{2\,\pi
\,n+x}}+ \left( -1 \right) ^{n} \left( 1/2\,{\pi}^{2}{n}^{2}-1/2
 \right) {{\rm e}^{n\pi\,x+1}}+{{\rm e}^{n\pi\,x}}+ \left(  \left( 1/2
\,{x}^{2}-x/2 \right) {\pi}^{3}{n}^{3}+ \left( -1/2+1/2\,{x}^{2}+x/2
 \right) {\pi}^{2}{n}^{2}+ \left( x/2-1/2\,{x}^{2} \right) \pi\,n+1/2-
1/2\,{x}^{2}-x/2 \right)  \left( -1 \right) ^{n}{{\rm e}^{x+1}}+
 \left(  \left( {x}^{2}-x \right) \pi\,n+{x}^{2}+x-1 \right) {{\rm e}^
{x}} \right) \pi\,n}{ \left( {\pi}^{2}{n}^{2}+1 \right) ^{3} \left( {
{\rm e}^{2\,\pi\,n}}-1 \right) }}
$$

Which in Mathematica becomes (using 20 terms)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here is plain text Mathematica code of the above

```
sol = Sum[-((1/((Pi^2*n^2 + 1)^3*(Exp[2*Pi*n] - 1)))*16*(Sin[
         n*Pi*y]*(((-(1/2))*Pi^2*n^2 + 1/2)*(-1)^n*
           Exp[1 - Pi*n*(x - 2)] + 
                  (1/2)*(-1)^
            n*(Pi*n + 1)*(x*Pi*(x - 1)*n - x^2 - x + 1)*(Pi*n - 1)*
           Exp[2*Pi*n + x + 1] - Exp[(-Pi)*n*(x - 2)] + 
                  ((x^2 - x)*Pi*n - x^2 - x + 1)*
           Exp[2*Pi*n + x] + (-1)^n*((Pi^2*n^2)/2 - 1/2)*
           Exp[n*Pi*x + 1] + Exp[n*Pi*x] + 
                  ((x^2/2 - x/2)*Pi^3*n^3 + (-(1/2) + x^2/2 + x/2)*
              Pi^2*n^2 + (x/2 - x^2/2)*Pi*n + 1/2 - x^2/2 - x/2)*(-1)^
            n*Exp[x + 1] + 
                  ((x^2 - x)*Pi*n + x^2 + x - 1)*Exp[x])*Pi*n)), {n, 1, 20}];
```

Here is a plot

```
   Plot3D[sol, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: (+1) Maple always up.